# Javascript .on("change",... not working in production, but works localhost

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

**Issue:** My javascript doesn't seem to be functioning on heroku, but does locally.  Although, there is other **javascript** I have on the application that does work.

I am using Bootstrap 4 for CSS mostly.  Majority of my JS is done manually not with the help of Bootstrap.

Here is a form that needs to have information dynamically submitted:

```
    <form action="/bank_accounts" method="POST" id="payment-form-1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="token" />
                                        <div class="form-row" "form-control">
                                          <label for="country">Country</label>
                                          <select id="country" class="form-control form-group">
                                            <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
                                            <option value="US">United States</option>
                                            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                                            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                                            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                                            <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                                            <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                                            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                                            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                                            <option value="NL">Netherland</option>
                                            <option value="NO">Norway</option>
                                            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
                                            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                                            <option value="FR">France</option>
                                            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                                            <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                                            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                                            <option value="ES">Spain</option>
                                          </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-row">
                                          <label for="currency">Currency</label>
                                          <select id="currency" class="form-control form-group">
                                            <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
                                          </select>
                                        </div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#country").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "US") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='USD'>US Dollar</option>");
        } else if (val == "AU") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='AUD'>AU Dollar</option>");
        } else if (val == "GB") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='EUR'>Euro</option><option value='GBP'>Pound</option>");
        } else if (val == "CA") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='CAD'>Canadian Dollar</option><option value='USD'>US Dollar</option>");
        } else if (val == "DK") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='EUR'>Euro</option><option value='DKK'>Danish Krone</option>");
        } else if (val == "NO") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='EUR'>Euro</option><option value='NOK'>Norwegian Krona</option>");
        } else if (val == "SE") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='EUR'>Euro</option><option value='SEK'>Swedish Krona</option>");
        } else if (val == "CH") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='EUR'>Euro</option><option value='CHF'>Swiss Franc</option>");
        } else if (val == "NZ") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='NZD'>NZ Dollar</option>");
        } else if (val == "AT" || "BE" || "FR" || "FI" || "GE" || "IE" || "NL" || "PT" || "ES" || "LU") {
            $("#currency").html("<option value='EUR'>Euro</option>");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce any error and please share the error which you are seeing in production

Comment: May be source file path problem which is commonly face in production

Comment: Now, I am not sure what is going down.  I tested in both Chrome and Brave and didn't work.  I just retested it, after no new commits, and it's working.  Is this possibly an error on Herokus side? I do not get it

Comment: Are you using Turbolinks?

Comment: @muistooshort yes will that cause errors?

Comment: You don't use `$(document).ready` with Turbolinks, you use `$(document).on('turbo links:load', ...)`.

Comment: @muistooshort is it normal that is works now, but didn't earlier or is it supposed to not work at all unless using `$(document).on('turbo links:load',` ?

Comment: `$(document).ready` will work with Turbolinks only the first time you hit the site, it won't work when you switch between pages.

Answer (score 0):

How are you determining what the users location is ?
If it is via a value the user sets in a dashboard then i am not sure.

If however the script requests the info depending on the users location
it could be a permission error depending if Heroku allows it or not.

If the function works locally then the code works, nothing wrong there.
TO me that sounds like a permission error of some sort.

If you are able to post some more info about the problem.
If possible also the console (error) output, that could be useful.

Comment: The country is based on their selection.. and btw this isn't the entire form.... but then based on their country will then appear the currencies they are able to select

Answer (score 0):

This may be a turbolinks issue. You can try

1) Remove the gem 'turbolinks' line from your Gemfile.

2) Remove the //= require turbolinks from your app/assets/javascripts/application.js .

3) Remove the two "data-turbolinks-track" => true hash key/value pairs from your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb .

Comment: Yes, that was messing with it in production and removing the turbo links from the layouts solved that.  Any way to keep turbo links and fix the JS code to adapt to it?